# How to query Visual Studio Team Services for historic data for reporting purposes?

Tags: reporting, azure-devops

I'm wondering how the built in charting function works? When I execute a query, for example work item type = bugs. I only get how many bugs there are today.

But if I go into the Charts tab, I can create a trend chart for the last 2 weeks.

Is there any way I can get access to those historic data and export them? For example, if I want to do the plotting in excel for some reporting? How would I write a query that gives me those information?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature cannot be achieved by work item query directly.

To get these information, you can use [Rest API](https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/integrate/api/overview) especially with ["As of a date"](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items#as-of-a-date). You can also consider to use [Power BI](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/report/powerbi/connect-vso-pbi-vs) to generate the report, for example: [Create trend charts](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/report/powerbi/create-trend-charts).